# How to access Meteor user collection on server and debug correctly

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

When validating objects for database insert, I would like to access the Meteor.users collection to let the user know if he added an event manager to the event who is stored in the database. I extended the discover meteor book example for my needs. I know of the [Meteor Accounts API](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_api), but I'm stuck at the moment how to proceed.

Here is the Meteor method

```
Meteor.methods({
  eventInsert: function(eventAttributes) {
    check(Meteor.userId(), String);
    check(eventAttributes, {
      title: String,
      shareInPercent: Number,
      eventDate: Date
    });

    var errors = validateEvent(eventAttributes);

    if (errors.title || errors.shareInPercent || errors.eventDate)
      throw new Meteor.Error('invalid-event', "Check your inputs again.");

    var user = Meteor.user();

    var event = _.extend(eventAttributes, {
      userId: user._id,
      author: user.username,
      submitted: new Date()
    });

    var eventId = Events.insert(event);

    return {
      _id: eventId
    };
  }
});

validateEvent = function (event) {
  var errors = {};
  if (!event.title)
    errors.title = "Please fill in an event title";
  if (!event.eventDate)
    errors.eventDate =  "Please enter a date";

  var eventManagersNotExisting = areEventManagersExistingUsers(event.eventManagers);

  return errors;
}

areEventManagersExistingUsers = function (eventManagers) {
  var eventManagersNotExisting = [];
  _.each(eventManagers, function(eventManager){
    var eventManagerFound = Meteor.users.findOne({username: eventManager});
  });
  return eventManagersNotExisting;
}
```

When an insert is triggered, the Meteor method is called, the validateEvent method is called in-between, which calls itself a helper method to check the users collection as seen here

```
var eventManagerFound = Meteor.users.findOne({username: eventManager});
```

If I'm right and because it should make sense, I can't put `console.log()` messages in the Meteor method, because the method is executed server side and the message won't appear in the browser console.

My first question therefore is, is there a way to look at log messages done on server side, similar to Node, where these messages just appear in the shell?

I read about the `meteor debug` and `meteor shell` command, but I'm not seeing any log messages appearing there, which I put into code.

Log messages in `validateEvent` and `areEventManagersExistingUsers` appear in the browser though.

Now my second question, when logging messages in `validateEvent` and `areEventManagersExistingUsers`, why do they show up in the browser console?

And the result of

```
var eventManagerFound = Meteor.users.findOne({username: eventManager});
```

is always undefined, only when eventManager is my own user, it's finding that entry.

But is it working for the Meteor.method call, and I'm seeing only a side effect of the proper execution or do I make something wrong here conceptionally?

**Edit:**

As said in the commentary below, to fix the console.log() when executing the Meteor method, I first had to [activate preserve log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346394/why-is-console-log-not-printing-anything) in the Chrome console, because the form submit is refreshing the site so fast, I just didn't see that the site was reloaded and the log erased.

But a requirement to see the log in the browser console, is the need to have a successful submit (i.e., I had to fill all fields correctly), for that I fixed the check

```
check(eventAttributes, {
  title: String,
  shareInPercent: Number,
  eventManagers: [String],
  eventDate: Date
});
```

But a log of `Meteor.users.find();` only returns my user and not all users in the database. Any idea how to get all of them without publishing the users collection?

Comment: Any `console.log` in the server code will show up in the console where you started meteor. So yes, you can absolutely use that server-side.

Comment: Ok, but a `console.log` following `eventInsert: function(eventAttributes) {`, does not yield a message in the browser. Any idea why?

Comment: `eventInsert` is a method, i.e., it runs on the server, not the browser

Comment: So when you say that logs in server code show up in the console, which console do you mean? I don't see them in the terminal at least.

Comment: which OS are you running? in linux and osx you will see any `console.log` output on the server side in the terminal where you started meteor.

Comment: OSX with Terminal at home and Windows 8 with Power Shell at work. But you gave me an idea, how to google the correct question and I found this StackOverflow -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346394/why-is-console-log-not-printing-anything Because it's a form, "preserve log" in the browser console needs to be checked, the messages appear in the console now. I also had to fix the check, and the log only appears when the submit is successful. Because I tried to let it crash during valdiateEvent. Nevertheless, `Meteor.users.find()` only returns my user, not all users, despite being on server