# No logs in mac terminal for cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, console.log

My question seems related to the below question, but I didn't quite get the solution provided
[Why is console.log() not printing anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346394/why-is-console-log-not-printing-anything)

When I run this program, it prints logs perfectly

```
const x = 'Hello';
const y = 'World!';
console.log(x, y);
```

But when I try this, it doesn't print `console.log`

```
Given("My demo test", async function (string, string2) {
    console.log("**************** Test Started ********************")

    if(string === "msn"){
        string = "https://msn.com";
    } else if (string === "google"){
        string = "https://google.com";
    }
    gotoPage(string)
    const imageLinkText = getText(':nth-child(2) > .gb_q')
    console.log(" **************** " + imageLinkText + " **************** " )
})
```

How can I get `console.log` output in the mac terminal?

I am using the below command to run my cypress tests in the chrome browser

`cypress run --headed chrome --env tags="@smoke"`

Comment: You should try `cy.log(...)` or emitting the console.log from the Cypress queue `cy.then(() => console.log(...))`.

Comment: I can't see `getText(':nth-child(2) > .gb_q')` actually returning text, most likely it's an object. Try `getText(':nth-child(2) > .gb_q').then(text => console.log(text))`.

Comment: `cy.log()` gives logs in the browser console but I want logs in bash or mac terminal. getText() is a function`return cy.get(selector).invoke("text");`

Comment: `cy.get(selector).invoke("text")` does not give you text, it gives you a Chainer object. You will not see anything useful in the console, even if you get it to print.

Comment: Even if I leave the element's text, general logging is also not working. I tried `cy.then(() => console.log("**************** Test Started ********************"));` and `console.log("**************** Test Started ********************")`

Comment: When using Cypress run mode you will need to log via a task - please see the duplicate question for details. Note the task setup has changed since that question, you can find details of current implementation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task).

Comment: @Fody thanks it worked. Only thing is invoke method return an object not text.